# could not login after changing session state mode in asp.net identity application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, azure-web-app-service, session-state, azure-redis-cache

I have created [asp.net identity application](http://www.asp.net/identity) (oath & owin) and created some users with registration and as i hosted this app on azure web app service so when i want to scale this from 1 instance to many i need to change inproc session state mode to custom or using redis as per recommendation.

**Existing**

```
 <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" >
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

**Changed To**

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" >
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

Though it has created **Sessions** table against pointed database but after that login did not work for any user?!!!! why???

Also I tried to replace it with redis provider as below but same issue

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionProvider">
      <providers>

        <add name="RedisSessionProvider"
             type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
             port="6380"
             host="[my url]"
             accessKey="[my key]"
             ssl="true" />

      </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

Comment: Are you getting error messages anywhere? Session should not affect Identity, as Identity does not use session.

Comment: @trailmax no error message just redirecting back to login page. yep identity use cookie for authentication but in case if i will use session variables then i need to consider this, right?

Comment: Currently having the identical issue. Updating a legacy Aps.Net MVC application with a  Redis cache session provider. Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: @Dmytro Did you figure out the problem? we're having the exact same issue... It's working fine when using InProc but it's going into a loop when using Azure redis.